# List Ramsey numbers?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

The *diagonal Ramsey number* $R(n,n)$ is the least number $m$ for which the following holds: in any edge-colouring of the complete graph $K_m$ in which each edge is coloured blue or red, there is a monochromatic $K_n.$

The *list Ramsey number* (my name for it) $R_\ell(n)$ is the least number $m$ for which the following holds: we can assign to each edge of the complete graph $K_m$ a list of two distinct colours so that, in any edge-colouring of $K_m$ where each edge receives a colour from its assigned list, there is a monochromatic $K_n.$

This definition is what we get if we regard the diagonal cases of Ramsey's theorem as assertions about the chromatic numbers of certain hypergraphs, and then replace chromatic numbers with list chromatic numbers.

Plainly $R_\ell(n)\le R(n,n),$ since we can simply assign the list $\{\text{blue, red}\}$ to each edge.

On the other hand, the probabilistic lower bound works just the same for $R_\ell(n)$ as for $R(n,n),$ so we have $R_\ell(n)\ge2^{n/2}.$

> **Questions.** Have such things been studied? Does it ever happen that $R_\ell(n)\lt R(n,n)$?

Of course we can define analogous variants of the (diagonal) multicolour and hypergraph Ramsey numbers, but maybe the above is enough insanity for today.

**P.S.** In a comment Thomas Bloom brought up the [list colouring conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_edge-coloring), which says that the list edge chromatic number of any graph is equal to the ordinary edge chromatic number. Here is a common generalization of the list colouring conjecture (for simple graphs) and the conjecture that $R_\ell(n)=R(n,n)$:

> **General Conjecture.** For any simple finite graphs $G$ and $H$ and any $c\in\mathbb N$ the following statements are equivalent:
>   
> (a) any edge-colouring of $G$ with at most $c$ colours contains a monochromatic copy of $H$;
>   
> (b) we can assign to each edge of $G$ a list of $c$ distinct colours so that, in any edge-colouring of $G$ where each edge receives a colour from its assigned list, there is a monochromatic copy of $H.$

This reduces to the list colouring conjecture (for simple graphs) when $H=K_{1,2},$ and it reduces to my question about $R_\ell(n)$ versus $R(n,n)$ when $G,H$ are complete graphs and $c=2.$

I suppose such questions are much too general to be worth thinking about. Maybe I should just ask:

> **Question 0.** Is $R_\ell(3)=6$? [Oops, see below.]

I guess that's true but the proof might be a bit tedious.

**P.P.S.** Actually it's quite easy to see that $R_\ell(3)=6=R(3,3),$ *i.e.*, if each edge of $K_5$ is assigned a list of two colours, we can give each edge a colour from its list without creating a monochromatic triangle. Since $R(4,4)=18,$ I guess the following is the smallest nontrivial case:

> **Question 1.** Is $R_\ell(4)=18$?

**P.P.P.S.** Although it doesn't fit in with my original question (which asked only about lists of size $2$), perhaps a better starting point would be to ask about the list version of the tricolour Ramsey number $R(3,3,3)=17.$ This amounts to asking whether the General Conjecture holds when $c=3$ and $H=K_3$ and $G=K_{16}:$

> **Question 2.** If a list of $3$ different colours is assigned arbitrarily to each edge of the complete graph $K_{16},$ can we colour each edge with a colour from its assigned list, without creating a monochromatic triangle?

Comment: Is there anything stopping me from never using a colour more than once?

Comment: Is there any reason to ever include a third color in any of the lists assigned to the edges? If we want to ensure a monochromatic $K_m$, why wouldn't the best strategy be to involve as few colors as possible?

Comment: @MichaelEngen: Some graphs have a chromatic number that is strictly larger than their list chromatic number, for example $K_{3,3}$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_coloring#Examples). This suggests, strange as it may seem, that involving as few colors as possible might not always be an optimal strategy for ensuring a monochromatic $K_m$.

Comment: @BenBarber There's nothing stopping you from "never using a colour more than once" but that would be a worst possible strategy. If you're the player who's assigning the lists, your goal is to force the player who's colouring the edges to make a monochromatic thing. Intuitively, it would seem that the best possible strategy would be to assign the same two colours to every edge. However, examples from [list colouring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_coloring) theory (bipartite graphs of arbitrarily large list chromatic number) suggest that this intuition may be wrong.

Comment: @MichaelEngen That is my question. Here is a motivating example. Draw the cycle graph $C_6$ and draw one more edge, joining a pair of diametrically opposite vertices. Can you assign a list of two colours to each vertex in such a way that your opponent, who must colour each vertex with a colour from its list, is forced to give the same colour to two adjacent vertices? Yes, you can, but *not* by assigning the same pair of colours to each vertex.

Comment: @MichaelEngen SPOILER: start anywhere, and assign the lists $\{1,2\},\ \{2,3\},\ \{1,3\},\ \{1,2\},\ \{2,3\},\ \{1,3\}$ to the vertices in cyclic order.

Comment: It is conjectured that, for edge colouring, list chromatic numbers and regular chromatic numbers always agree (and this known for at least edge colourings of bipartite graphs). This might be (weak) evidence that list Ramsey numbers also agree with regular Ramsey numbers.

Comment: @ThomasBloom Good point. I edited my question to include mention of a common generalization.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification: I knew I had to be missing something, and it turned out to be simply misreading the question.

Comment: When I saw the question title "list Ramsey numbers" I expected the answer to be "1, 2, 6, 18, (subsequent terms unknown)"...

Comment: A different notion of list Ramsey number has been considered by Bustamante and Stein. See here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.05190.

Comment: @DavidConlon Thanks for that interesting reference.

Comment: @bof Another follow-up paper on list Ramsey numbers is here: 

 https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15175 

We would like to properly cite you. Do you mind sharing your name for this purpose?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

we stumbled upon the same concept in a different way and discovered this topic when looking if someone studied it already.

We have figured out some interesting things, such as:

- disproving your general conjecture (it is false for matchings),
- proving it is true for stars (except for very small stars),
- proving behaviour is very different between the Ramsey numbers even for 3-uniform  hypergraphs,
- obtaining several other results giving various bounds for general (hyper)graphs.

Your original question of whether it is equal for cliques stays open, even for multiple colours.

Here is the link to the paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.07018

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.